# Kivy, ScreenManager says no screen while switching to previous screen

Tags: python, kivy

Now I'm already using ScreenManager in a different project where it works with no issues. But amazingly same setup doesn't work in any other projects. Simply can't figure out why my screen can only be switched to a new screen (which was not displayed before) and not to any previous screens. I'm posting a simple code to show this phenomenon. Please advice what am I seriously missing. Thank you.

## screenmanager_test.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')
import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def setName(self,*args):
        FirstPopup().open()

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class FirstPopup(Popup):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SmTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = MyScreenManager()
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_scr"))
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name="second_scr"))
        return sm

SmTestApp().run()
```

## smtest.kv

```
#: kivy 1.11.0

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main_scr'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 100,100
        spacing: 50

        Label:
            text: 'Welcome to Main Screen'
            font_size: 35

        Button:
            text: 'Options'
            font_size: 15
            on_release: root.setName(*args)

        Button:
            text: 'Next Screen'
            font_size: 15
            on_release: app.root.current = 'second_scr'

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second_scr'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding:100,100
        spacing:50

        Label:
            text: 'This is your second screen'
            font_size: 35
        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            font_size: 25
            on_release: app.root.current = 'main_scr'

<FirstPopup>:
    title: 'Options Window'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400,370
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : 'vertical'
        Label:
            text : "Checkbox options listed here"
        Button:
            text: "OK"
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Comment: Your `MyScreenManager` class is not actually used. Your line `sm = MyScreenManager()` is useless since it is followed by `sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())`. However, your code works fine for me (after removing the kivy 1.11 requirements, since I am running kivy v1.10.1).

Comment: Yes, as you said MyScreenManager class is not actually being used. But that has got nothing to do with the issue. I tried removing my kivy requirements line. Still no use. I get the below message when trying to go back to the previous screen. Is this some kind of bug in 1.11.0 ?

   **File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1065, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "main_scr".**

Comment: If you remove the `os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'`, does that have any effect?

Comment: @Mashriq: Please post the actual error message and Python trace back, so that we can trouble shoot the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @ikolim: Please check the following thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946094/kivy-screenmanager-error-while-using-transition-effects-having-shader-effect

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is what I have found. I removed that FadeTransition effect and things came back to normal. I checked all other available transition methods and found that out of 8 , 4 transition style causes the program to exit. The effects which are causing this error are Fade, Wipe, FallOut and RiseIn.

If this is caused due to some other wrongly set paramenter, I don't know. If anyone can give an explanation then that would be fine. If not any how the cause has been identified. Thank you @John Anderson.